# Making Python Package - Failing on pyproject.toml - Following Tutorial and Getting Error

Tags: python, build, package, toml

I am following the Python Package Tutorial:

https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

I have stepped through exactly as described.

I create my pyproject.toml file as follows:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools","wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

tutorial says create as follows:

[image]

Later tutorial says run the following command to build a wheel for creating the package:

[image]

and I run command as follows (slightly different because I don't have py in my environment variable):

[image]

But I get the following error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?  It is almost exactly the same!

Comment: can you share the file? The error message doesn't match the posted file content

Comment: Not sure how to attach file....don't see a way to add.

Comment: pastebin or any file sharing service

Comment: Ok.  Let me try that and I'll post link here.  May take a little while .

Comment: Here is a link to the file:  http://www.filedropper.com/pyproject

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the content of this file. The only strange thing is the byte order mark in the beginning, Python might not handle it correctly. [updated file](http://www.filedropper.com/pyprojecttoml)

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain this.  Something must have been wrong or corrupted during the file creation.  I recreated and it worked.